# Yii : How to change widget folder

Tags: php, yii

when I use  `$this->widget('someWidget',array() }`  I need to put the in `/protected/components` folder.

What if I want to some of my Widget inside `/protected/anotherFolder` ?

Can i set up  something to make the $this->widget() function find another folder without change the parameter inside $this->widget() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to put it in anotherfolder, then you have to give it the full path to be able to use it like in controller:

```
 $this->widget('application.anotherFolder.someWidgetFolder.someWidgetClass' , $params);
```

or you can make an alias in config/main

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('anotherFolder', dirname(__FILE__) . '/../anotherFolder/someWidgetFolder');
```

and make it like

```
 $this->widget('anotherFolder.someWidgetClass' , $params);
```

Comment: This is just what I hate.

Comment: wow ! that's make sense a lot ! I chose you ! I mean , your answer.

Comment: lol @ArekŻelechowski answer the same thing, but I appreciate example.

Comment: I think, that my solution is better, because you do not have to mix array with function calls in config file.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in config like that:

```
return array(
    'aliases' => array(
            'bootstrap' => 'ext.bootstrap',
        ),
);
```